# Why Powermock PrepareForTest prevent mock inject?

Tags: powermock

My code is like below:

```
public class RealWorldBoImpl extends AbstractBoImpl<T> implements SomeBo{}
```

And

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({RealWorldBoImpl.class})
public class RealWorldBoImplTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private RealWorldBoImpl realWorldBo;
    @Mock
    private RealWorldDAO realWorldDAO;

    @Test
    public void changeStatusMainSubString() throws Exception {
        long id = 1L;
    }
```

In this case, realWorldDAO cannot inject to realWorldBo. But when I delete PrepareForTest, it works.

I also tried other classes, they worked well. It seems RealWorldBoImpl is special that when prepare for it, it will not inject mocks correctly.

I debugged this code, and found that, in org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldInitializer#checkParameterized, constructor.getParameterTypes() is not empty and has a constructor with the class IndicateReloadClass.

```
private void checkParameterized(Constructor<?> constructor, Field field) {
        if(constructor.getParameterTypes().length == 0) {
            throw new MockitoException("the field " + field.getName() + " of type " + field.getType() + " has no parameterized constructor");
        }
    }
```

But I don't know what's special with RealWorldBoImpl. It just extends a parent class and implements an interface. Does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

When PowerMock prepares a class which has a superclass other than `Object` it adds a constructor to the class which takes an argument of type `org.powermock.core.IndicateReloadClass`.

Why PowerMock does this? PowerMock implements superclass constructor suppression through this mechanism.
In your case because `RealWorldBoImpl` derives from `AbstractBoImpl` PowerMock adds the following constructors to `RealWorldBoImpl`, `AbstractBoImpl` classes:

```
  public RealWorldBoImpl(IndicateReloadClass var1) {
    super(var1);
  }

  public AbstractBoImpl(IndicateReloadClass var1) {
    super(); //assuming the parent class is Object otherwise super(var1)
  }
```

and changes the default no-arg constructor of `RealWorldBoImpl` to the following:

```
  public RealWorldBoImpl() {
    Object var1 = MockGateway.constructorCall(Desc.getClazz("org.example.RealWorldBoImpl"),
        new Object[0], Desc.getParams("()V"));
    if (var1 != MockGateway.PROCEED) {
      super((IndicateReloadClass)null);
    } else {
      super();
    }
  }
```

That was the PowerMock part now let's get to the Mockito part.

Mockito has two injection strategies (`MockInjectionStrategy`): `ConstructorInjection` and `PropertyAndSetterInjection`.

`ConstructorInjection` uses constructor to inject mocks and is used if the injectee has at least one non-default constructor (a constructor that takes at least an argument). In case the injectee has only a no-arg constructor, Mockito uses `PropertyAndSetterInjection` which uses setter method and if there is no setter method it injects the mocks directly by setting the field's value through reflection.

In your case when you prepare `RealWorldBoImpl` class you have a constructor with one argument and Mockito uses `ConstructorInjection` to inject mocks to your object through the constructor that was added by PowerMock (and as there's no mock of type `IndicateReloadClass`, Mockito passes null to the constructor but that does not matter as the constructor does nothing) and as a result no mocks are injected.

So how can you solve the problem? If you have more than one mock to inject, then add a constructor to the injectee class with as many arguments as the number of mocks you want to inject. As long as you have a constructor with more than one argument, injection will work otherwise your injectee class should have `Object` as it superclass.

If you have only one mock to inject, you can add a dummy argument to the constructor to make Mockito choose your constructor over the one added by PowerMock:

```
public RealWorldBoImpl(RealWorldDAO realWorldDAO, String dummy) {
    this.realWorldDAO = realWorldDAO;
}
```